# How to resolve log4j dependencies conflict?

Tags: java, slf4j

When I start my application, I am seeing this message below. How to get rid of this multiple binding issue?

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/congin/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.6.2/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/congin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]


SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

My dependencies show that several slf4j 'omitted for duplicates'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have only one implementation jar in class path (Maven dependencies). 
Now you have 2, so choose one:

- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar or
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar

If somehow one of them is transitive dependency - find from where it comes and use Maven `<exclusions>` tag in dependency to take it out.

Comment: omitted are fine they are not in classpath. As I can see you have slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21 as transitive depenedency. But in classpath there is also log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar. Are you running your app in server? perhaps server can have 2.6.2 in its bootstrap classpath. So first try `<exclusions>` for log4j12-1.7.21 in `com.jd:jsf` `<dependency>`.

Comment: But log4j12-1.7.21 are in several other libraries. Should I exclude in each of them?

Comment: Perhaps yes, just try one by one.